# Is it okay to use threading pool inside django view?

Tags: python, django, multithreading, gunicorn, python-multithreading

Inside django view I need to make several parallel requests to the database (solr) and I want to use threading pool for this. Is this okay?

My concern is that django might not like another threads inside threads. I tested my solution in gunicorn setup (with default worker type) and everything works fine. But I still have some doubts. Do you know any pitfalls?

Here is simple example of the view:

```py
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

def foo_view(request):
   with ThreadPool() as p:
       results = p.starmap(func_with_solr_request, [...params...])
   return serialize(results)
```

Comment: Why do you consider threading to be the solution here? Most databases does parallelism if you're only doing reads. What exactly is it you're trying to solve?

Comment: "databases does parallelism if you're only doing reads" But I don't want to wait for each separate read. I need to send N parallel requests and just wait until they all will be completed.

Comment: You shouldn't need to wait for them. Django does the queries lazily, so they'll only be executed when you read from them. So if your database supports parallell reads, then Django should (in theory, but verify anyways) utilize that functionality.

Comment: I'm using Solr (similar to elasticsearch), not django ORM supported DBs. And I believe that pysolr lib doesn't support such fancy things as lazy execution.

Comment: Okay, I had to look it up because I was under the impression you where using a SQL-database, which Solr apparently isn't. I highly doubt that starting threads would have any major pitfalls, as Django starts a new process for every request. Also, your function is sequential as far as Django concerns, as you start and join your threads within the function. However, considering that Solr seems well-developed and feature-full, it might have some way of doing what you want without manual threading. But otherwise, threading might be a valid solution.